# Assign multiple PHP variables to MySQL values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, content-management-system

I'm doing a simple CMS for a website, it has been all done like this:

#### (config.php)

```
<?php
$title= "My website title";
$something= "Some text here";
// There are around 300 other vars like that.
// All text from the website comes from this file.
?>
```

#### (example.php)

```
<php require ('config.php'); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><?php echo $something ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But now I want to pass it to MySQL. I didn't do it at first because I was really noob at coding, but during the process of getting everything together, I felt ready to do it using a database and a admin panel.

Assuming I already have a MySQLi connection established, how can make config.php variables pull his data from the database, instead of a static string?

#### How can I do that without overload the system with hundreds of queries per page load?

Comment: where is your database connection string? (in which file?)

Comment: It will be in config.php. Here's how the connection is being made for install.php: http://pastebin.com/pF7Dgb71 // mysql_config.php just hold the values for database url, admin and username

Comment: So, there will be different variables for different pages. right?

Comment: Yes, but currently all pages pull their data from the same file - config.php, wich holds all variables

Answer (score 0):

If you want different variables in different pages from same file. Then, get your current page name by,

```
$page_name = substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
```

On the basis of page name pull out your information from database.

**config.php**

```
<?php
  if($page_title == 'example.php'){
    $title= $db_title;               // This variable will come from database...
    $something= $db_something;
  }
  else if($page_title == 'example_2.php'){
    $title= $db_title_2;
    $something= $db_something_2;
  }
  etc...
?>
```

You can use same config.php file in every pages...

Comment: That's a workaround, but during the research I found something: Cache! It seems to be the answer to the problem, I'll start messing with this: https://github.com/khoaofgod/phpfastcache